# How and where to dispose dbcontext using unity PerRequestLifetimeManager

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I am using unity IOC to inject the dbcontext in the relevant classes in a Web API. I am using custom lifetime manager as shown below:

```
public class PerRequestLifetimeManager : LifetimeManager 
{
    private readonly object key = new object();

    public override object GetValue()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null &&
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(key))
            return HttpContext.Current.Items[key];
        else
            return null;
    }

    public override void RemoveValue()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(key);
    }

    public override void SetValue(object newValue)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = newValue;
    }
}
```

This is injected in global.asax as this:

// context - one context per http request
            container.RegisterType(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());

In dbcontext class we have this:

```
public class BudgetControlDbContext : DbContext, IBudgetControlDbContext
{
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        this._isDisposed = true;
    }

    public bool IsDisposed
    {
        get { return this._isDisposed; }
    }
}
```

**Question:**
Now how to dispose the dbcontext and where that code should be?

Comment: This is worth a read:  https://oncodedesign.com/extending-unity-container-for-idisposable-instances-1st-approach/

Comment: I think it's best to use `PerRequestLifetimeManager` provided by Unit.Mvc5 nuget package and leave the life cycle management to it. Microsoft knows the best how to manage the objects and dispose them when time comes.

Comment: Any Ideas please?